# The command \tkzDefPointByFct from tkz-fct package does't work

Tags: tkz-fct

I try to use the command **\tkzDefPointByFct** in the following example but it gives several errors:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}



\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \tkzInit[xmin=-2.5,xmax=4.3,ymin=-3.5,ymax=1.5]
        \tkzGrid[color=gray!60]
        \tkzAxeXY[font=\small]

        \tkzFct[domain=-2.5:4,line width=1.5pt]{(-(x+2)*(x-3)**2/4))}

        \tkzDefPointByFct[draw](2)
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The errors are:

```
! FP error: Evaluation results in multiple values!.

! Undefined control sequence.\tkzDefPointByFct[draw](2)

! I don't know how to \FP@upn[].\tkzDefPointByFct[draw](2)
```

This problem seems to be similar to this question ["Strange behavior using tkz-fct"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311478/strange-behavior-using-tkz-fct), but I tried the solution and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Have you installed gnuplot?
http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html

Comment: Typo, you're missing an opening `(` in the function declaration.

Comment: Hello, gnuplot is installed, and the graphics look good. except when I try to define a point through the function.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! @TorbjørnT. it's the parenthesis. Sorry for the question.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.